# Disable input field when checkbox toggled (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a list of checkboxes and with every checkbox, there is an input field. If I check the checkbox, the inputfield has to be disabled.
Example:

```
Checkbox 1 - Input 1
Checkbox 2 - Input 2
Checkbox 3 - Input 3
```

The real code:

```
<table id="food" width="580px">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Eten</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1_1" value="" /></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="todo_1_1" value="7" />
            <td>Braadworst</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_1_1" size="4" value="" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1_2" value="" /></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="todo_1_2" value="5" />
            <td>Witte worst</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_1_2" size="4" value="" /></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Only the input field with the same number may be disabled ...

Through Google I found: http://techchorus.net/disable-and-enable-input-elements-div-block-using-jquery

The example works perfectly, but is there a way to do this without pre-defining the names? In my case, it is impossible to know the names, so they have to be determined when toggling the checkbox, no?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the markup?  It's definitely possible, but we need to know where the elements are in relation to each other.

Comment: @Nick is correct - if the elements are related in some consistent way (say, the checkbox and the text field grouped within a common `<div>` or `<li>` or `<span>`), then your script can "find" the text field by working through the DOM from the checkbox.

Comment: @Nick @Pointy I've updated the question with real code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few corrections to the markup first: that hidden input needs to be inside a `<td>` and the header row needs a closing `</tr>`, then you can do this:

```
​$('#food').delegate(':checkbox', 'change', function(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
$(':checkbox').change(); //set state initially
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SMjFs/1/), we're using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get up to the `<tr>`, then finding inputs of `[type=text]` using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the example and the code! I've tried the example and the text field is disabled when the checkbox isn't checked. Can it be changed to this: Input text field is disabled when checkbox is checked? Where do I put the javascript-code? Just as normal JQuery code in the head?

Comment: @koko- ahh, just change `!this.checked` to `this.checked`, remove `!`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It seems I have to learn a LOT of JQuery :-)

Answer (score 6):

if you have this ***"very"*** simple structure

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" /><input type="text" name="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="" /><input type="text" name="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="" /><input type="text" name="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="" /><input type="text" name="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="" /><input type="text" name="" />​
```

you can

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
  $(this).next().attr('disabled',!this.checked);
})​;
```

[here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awBvq/)

but then I know you don't have that ***"very"*** simple structure so, read the following and get the idea from above...

1. [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)
2. [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

If you can provide the structure of your html, much better...

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` is a *long* way to say `this.checked` :)  You can shorten that down to: `$(':checkbox').change(function(){ $(this).next().attr('disabled',!this.checked); });`.