# Using a checkbox to disable all the input fields in a table row

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109584/disable-input-field-when-checkbox-toggled-jquery) answered question, I am attempting to have a checkbox at the end of each row of my table, which contains 2 text field inputs per row.

I would like the inputs to become "disabled" if the checkbox has been checked.

**My HTML:**

```
<table class="forecast">
    <tr>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer A</th>
      <th>Answer B</th>
      <th>Not applicable</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quesiton 1</td>   
      <td>
        <input id="" name="q1a" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="" title="" id="" name="q1b" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
      </td>
      <td >
        <input type="checkbox" id="" class="notused" name="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quesiton 2</td>   
      <td>
        <input id="" name="q2a" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="" title="" id="" name="q2b" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
      </td>
      <td >
        <input type="checkbox" id="" class="notused" name="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My attempted jQuery:**

```
$('.notused').delegate(':checkbox', 'change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
$(':checkbox').change();
```

Nothing happens when I check the box, there are no errors in my console. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked property, Also prefer [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register event handlers

```
$('.forecast').on('change', ':checkbox', function () {
    var $inpts = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').prop('disabled', this.checked);
    if(this.checked){
        $inpts.val(0)
    }
}).find(':checkbox').change();
```

*(Assuming you are using jQuery >= 1.7)*

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kPSbP/)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly (yes, I'm on jQuery 1.9.1) I will accept this answer when the time runs out

Comment: And may I ask, how could I also set the input values to 0 if it was checked?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work (The edit) should the var have a $ for sure?

Comment: @Gideon checkout the fiddle... is it working for you? it is working for me

Comment: yes the fiddle is - in chrome however I was getting an uncaught exception and the code was not showing `var $inpts =`  but instead `var  =` I removed the $ sign such that it was `var inpts= ` and this is now working. Something strange?

Comment: `$inpts` is a valid variable name... what is the locale used in your system

Comment: jQuery as part of a PHP 5.x variable?

Comment: how do I make it possible for type="number" . find('input:number') or find('input:numeric') does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Using `Jquery 1.9.1`

```
$(function(){
$('.forecast').delegate(':checkbox', 'change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vrghG/)

[Updated Demo with `0` value](http://jsfiddle.net/vrghG/1/)