# semantic ui disable input field when checkbox toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a toggle checkbox and 2 input fields. What I want to achieve is to disable the input fields when the checkbox is unchecked, and vice versa. Here's my code.

```
<div class="inline fields">
  <div class="four wide field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="a4" name="a4" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox">
      <label>A4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Grayscale</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="gray" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
```

I've researched using behaviors for checkboxes like attach events, etc or using callbacks but I don't know how to use them properly. [I've also tried implementing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109584/disable-input-field-when-checkbox-toggled-jquery/3109696#3109696) but I think the `.next()` doesn't fit my problem. I tried experimenting and researching but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs should be disabled at the first instance. Then enabled whenever the box is checked.

```js
$('#a4').change(function(){
  $('#gray').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
  $('#colored').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline fields">
  <div class="four wide field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="a4" name="a4" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox">
      <label>A4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Grayscale</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input id="gray" name="gray" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input id="colored" name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the link you provided, I came up with this solution.

```js
$('#a4').change(function(){
  $('input[name=gray]').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
  $('input[name=colored]').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline fields">
  <div class="four wide field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="a4" name="a4" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox" checked>
      <label>A4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Grayscale</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="gray" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you might want to set some IDs on your text inputs so you don't have to use `input[name=gray]`. I personally prefer IDs to this kind of syntax.

*EDIT:*

Added checked attribute to the checkbox to reflect OP needs.

Comment: I ran you code snippet and the inputs are working at first instance even though the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `on` function with the parameter "change" to add an event listener to the checkbox changing, then inside the callback part use the input selector by name 'gray'  so set the `disabled` property to the inverse of the checked state of the checkbox.

If you want to do this for all checkboxes in a form with many items, as long as they follow the same basic template design, you can use `parent()` and `find()` together to find the input elements of a certain type within a certain parent element.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("input[type='text']").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline fields">
  <div class="four wide field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="a4" name="a4" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox" />
      <label>A4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Grayscale</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="gray" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled="true">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="inline fields">
  <div class="four wide field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="a4" name="a4" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox" />
      <label>C4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Grayscale</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="gray" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled="true">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inline fields">
  <div class="four wide field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="a4" name="a4" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox" />
      <label>B4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Grayscale</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="gray" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled="true">
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="six wide field">
    <label>Colored</label>
    <div class="ui right labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">Php</div>
      <input name="colored" value="1.00" placeholder="0.00" type="text" disabled>
      <div class="ui basic label">/page</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```